# $f$ admits multiple roots iff $\mathrm{gcd}(f,f')\neq 1_F$

Tags: polynomials

I want to check if this constitutes a proof for the following:

Let $f\in F[X]$ with $f=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kX^k$ and let $f'=\sum_{k=0}^na_kkX^{k-1}$ denote the formal derivative of $f$. Show that if $f$ has a non simple root in a field extension $E\supset F$ iff $\text{gcd}(f,f')  \neq 1$.

Proof: let $f\in F[X]$ have a root $a$. Then with the euclidean algorithm $f(X)=(X-a)g(X)$ with $g\in F[X]$. If $a$ is not a simple root then $$(X-a) | g(X) \iff g(X)=(X-a)h(X),~h(X) \in F[X]$$

With the product rule
$$f'(X)=g(X)+(X-a)g'(X)$$
and
$$f'(X)=(X-a)h(X)+(X-a)g'(X)$$
So $(X-a)\ |\ f'$ and $\gcd(f,f')\neq 1$.

Comment: You assumed that $f$ has a root of multiply $>1$, and showed that $gcd(f, f')\neq1$. Now you need to show the opposite.

Comment: This looks like the proof of $\Rightarrow$ only.

Comment: Is $F$ algebraically closed?

Comment: @MichaelBurr it wasn't stated in the problem

Comment: What if $f=(x^2+1)^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.  Then $f$ doesn't have multiple roots of $\mathbb{R}$ (it doesn't have any!), but $f'=2(x^2+1)2x$, so $\gcd(f,f')\not=1$.  Could you please clarify what you mean by simple roots.  Perhaps the roots are simple in an algebraic closure?

Comment: Oh, it said in a field extension. Let me edit the question

Comment: If $F=\Bbb Q$, then $(x^2-2)^2$ has nontrivial gcd with its derivative $4x(x^2-2)$, but has no roots in $F$

Comment: yeah youre correct that would be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did proves that if $f$ has a multiple root, then $\gcd(f,f')\neq1$. In order to prove the reverse implication, you could observe that if all roots of $f$ are simple, then $f$ and $f'$ have no common root and that therefore (although this is not trivial) $f$ and $f'$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Perhaps all roots of $f$ in an algebraic closure are simple?

Answer (score 0):

For the converse implication, say $L$ the splitting field of $F$.

Assume that $g(X):=\gcd(f(X),f'(X))\neq 1_L$. Suppose for contradiction that all the roots of $f(X)$ in $L$ are distinct. So,
$f(X)=c(X-\alpha_1)\dotsb (X-\alpha_n)\in L[X]$
where $c\in L$ and $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n\in L$ are all distinct. Then,
$$f'(X)=\sum_{i=2}^n c(X-\alpha_1)\dotsb(X-\alpha_{i-1})(X-\alpha_{i}) \dotsb (X-\alpha_n)\in L[X].$$
Now, since $g(X)\neq 1_L$, it must be $\deg g(X)\geq 1$. So, any root of the common factor $g(X)$ ***must
be a common root*** of $f(X)$ and $f'(X)$. Therefore, there is some $\alpha\in \{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$  such that $f'(\alpha)=0_L$. Without any loss of generality, say that $\alpha$ is $\alpha_1$. Then,
$$f'(\alpha_1)=0_L\iff c(\alpha_1-\alpha_2)\dotsb (\alpha_1-\alpha_n)=0_L \iff \alpha_1\in \{\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n\}.$$
The latter is impossible, since we supposed all the roots are distinct. So $f(X)$ has repeated roots in $L$.

*Hope that helps!*